# How can i upload a file and add file information and user details to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that should collect user data and photograph, but each time i hit the register button the file will upload but the other form variable wont register in the database

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) {
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare(' INSERT INTO tbl_users 
            ( userName, userMarital, userReligion, userNationality, 
                userCountry, userState, userCity, userEmail, userPhone, 
                userPhoto, userQualification, userFeild, userInstitution, 
                userNok, nokRelationship, nokNumber, userFacebook, 
                userInstagram, userTwiter, userColor, userEye, userHeight, 
                userHip, userBurst, userWaist, userShoulder, userLikes, 
                userDislikes, userTalents, userFavcolor, userFavpal, 
                tokenCode)  
        VALUES (:userName, :userMarital, :userReligion, :userNationality, 
                :userCountry, :userState, :userCity, :userEmail, 
                :userPhone, :userPhoto, :userQualification, :userFeild, 
                :userInstitution, :userNok, :nokRelationship, :nokNumber, 
                :userFacebook, :userInstagram, :userTwiter, :userColor, 
                :userEye, :userHeight, :userHip, :userBurst, :userWaist, 
                :userShoulder, :userLikes, :userDislikes, :userTalents, 
                :userFavcolor, :userFavpal, :activeCode)');

    $stmt->bindParam(':userName', $userName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userMarital', $userMarital);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userReligion', $userReligion);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userNationality', $userNationality);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userCountry', $userCountry);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userState', $userState);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userCity', $userCity);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userEmail', $userEmail);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userPhone', $userPhone);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userPhoto', $userPhoto);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userQualification', $userQualification);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userFeild', $userFeild);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userInstitution', $userInstitution);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userNok', $userNok);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nokRelationship', $nokRelationship);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nokNumber', $nokNumber);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userFacebook', $userFacebook);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userInstagram', $userInstagram);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userTwiter', $userTwiter);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userColor', $userColor);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userEye', $userEye);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userHeight', $userHeight);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userHip', $userHip);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userBurst', $userBurst);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userWaist', $userWaist);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userShoulder', $userShoulder);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userLikes', $userLikes);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userDislikes', $userDislikes);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userTalents', $userTalents);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userFavcolor', $userFavcolor);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userFavpal', $userFavpal);
    $stmt->bindParam(':activeCode', $code);


    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
        $response['status'] = 'success';
        $response['message'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> &nbsp; registered sucessfully, you may login now';
    } else {

        $response['status'] = 'error'; // could not register
        $response['message'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; could not register, try again later';
    } 
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done?  You're using a _lot_ of variables without showing where/how they are assigned.

Comment: I don't see any evidence in the code that you execute the prepared statement.

Comment: `prepare` -> `bind` -> `execute` ?? Where is your execute?

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on what I see in your code example, you have prepared a query and used bind params but never executed the query like:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

I supposed you're using mysqli, if you're using a different driver please seach how to execute a query.